# how to read uploaded files from xampp

Tags: php, xampp

I have this code for uploading files on the server:

```
<tr>
<td>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploadaction.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Select the image: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" />

</td>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
</td>
</tr>
```

And here's the action form:

```
<?php
$target_path = "uploads/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>
```

What php function will I use?
Can you give me an example on how to read the file back and display it in the browser?
Please help, thanks.

Comment: *(reference)* http://de.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: If the file was uploaded successfully, it should be sitting in the directory that you sent it to. From there how you choose display it kind of depends on what the file is.

Comment: Its an image file, how do I view it from the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PHP's documentation about file uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) should solve your problem. If it does not and you still have a question about it, feel free to come back and ask again.